# How to set functionality of <BS>

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode

I just realized that the standard setting of  is actual not 'going back one space', but deleting everything selected. Is there some basic way to get that some functionality in Vim visual mode, without resorting to  in normal mode.

Also I noticed that  was even listed in `:map`, which I found odd...

EDIT: Okay, I now tried it with `vim -u NONE` and then `:map`, which showed me that...

```
v  <BS>          "-d
v  <D-x>         "*d
v  <D-c>         "*y
v  <D-v>         "-d"*P
n  <D-v>         "*P
```

These are the only mappings, but why are these mapping there anyway? I tried `vunmap <bs>` but that doesn't work (it still doesn't go back like I want it to)

EDIT2:
Okay so I made a screencapture to show my dilemma.
It should be self explanatory: On the left I call vim normally, load all my plugins, but then disable my mappings.
When I start visual mode I can use `<bs>` (and `<space>`) to change lines.

On the right, using `vim -u NONE` I can't do that.

There must be some setting to set that behavior...

[image: Vim picture]

Comment: So, when you press backspace you want the selection to reduce by one character? Also, are you using Vim on linux or on windows?

Comment: Try these two settings if that is the case. `set backspace=2` and 

`set backspace=indent,eol,start`.

Comment: I want to go regardless to the character before, basically `?.<cr>`.

Comment: what do you mean 'go'?  Do you want that deleted?

Comment: No. Just changing the cursor position.

Comment: This is the default behavior for me. Are you sure that you don't have `<BS>` mapped to delete? Try it when stating vim with `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: Yeah. The default behavior of `<BS>` in `visual mode` is to move the cursor to the previous letter. It does nothing else. So, may be can you take a screen grab of what's happening when you press `<BS>` ?

Comment: `Also I noticed that was even listed in :map, which I found odd` If by that you mean that you see `<BS>` mapped in visual mode you got your answer: The default behavior of `<BS>` in visual mode is to do the same as `h`, if you observe a different behavior it means that you (or a plugin) remapped the key in visual mode.

Comment: Usually doing `vim -u NONE` shouldn't have any mappings. But Gvim  seems to have a few mappings still, I don't have a `<BS>` mapping though. But it looks like in your case it has been mapped to delete it. Did you try the mappings I gave in a comment above? Did that over write this mapping?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop That allows me to delete beyond the starting point in insert mode, but it doesn't change the behavior in visual mode...

Comment: Okay I just figured it out, it's set by the `compatible` option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just figured it out, it's set by the `compatible` option...

It sets the `whichwrap` option, which actually controls this behavior.
The `vi` default is `""`, while the `vim` default is `"b,s"`, which is the space and the backspace key.

Comment: Haha. I would have never guessed it because of `compatible`. Why do you have it set anyway? One of the first things told in Vim tutorials is to have `set nocompatible` as the first line of your vimrc file.

Comment: Of course I had compatible set, but I was testing a plugin I wrote and was confused about that irrational behavior (because I tested it using `vim -u NONE` and than `:source`ing the plugin)